# C++ Destructor, EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory

Tags: c++, destructor

I plan to use a sorted array to construct a balanced binary search tree. All worked well until the end of the program. It seems that the destructor of the binary search tree has some problem.

Error information:

> Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
>   Reason: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at address: 0x00007fff5f3ffff8
>   0x0000000100002857 in BST_Node::~BST_Node (this=0x100100920) at
>   BST_Node.h:18             ~BST_Node() {delete parent; delete left; delete
>   right;}

```
#ifndef BST_NODE_H
#define BST_NODE_H

#include <cstddef>

class BST_Node {
    public:
        BST_Node(int k) : key(k), parent(NULL), left(NULL), right(NULL) {}
        ~BST_Node() {if (parent!=NULL) delete parent;if (left!=NULL) delete left;if (right!=NULL) delete right;}
        // data member
        int key;
        BST_Node* parent;
        BST_Node* left;
        BST_Node* right;
};

#endif

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "BST_Tree.h"
#include "BST_Node.h"

using namespace std;

// use recursion to construct the tree. Find the mid of the array to be the root of the subtree. Use left part of the array to construct the left subtree and right part to construct the right subtree.
BST_Node* CreateTree(vector<int> &a, int start, int end) {
    if (end<start) {
        return NULL;
    } else {
        int mid = (start+end+1)/2;
        BST_Node* p = new BST_Node(a[mid]);
        BST_Node* l_tmp = CreateTree(a, start, mid-1);
        if (l_tmp)
            l_tmp->parent = p;
        p->left = l_tmp;
        BST_Node* r_tmp = CreateTree(a, mid+1, end);
        if (r_tmp)
            r_tmp->parent = p;
        p->right = r_tmp;
        return p;
    }
}

int main() {
    vector<int> a;
    a.push_back(0);
    a.push_back(1);
    a.push_back(2);
    a.push_back(3);
    a.push_back(4);
    a.push_back(5);
    a.push_back(6);
    BST_Tree t;
    t.root = CreateTree(a, 0, 6);
    t.InOrderWalk(t.root);
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you considered using smart pointers? This is exactly the kind of problems they are meant to solve

Comment: Remove `delete parent`. That's not how a recursive call should be made,

Comment: So you're deleting the parent, which will run the parents destructor, which will delete its left and right child, who each will delete their parent. Which will be a problem.

Comment: You are trying to destruct the "parent" 2x or tryin to acces member of already destructed "parent". How work the destructor of BST_Tree?

Comment: @Andy Prowl: the key problem here is to see that `parent` is a non-owning pointer. Blindly replacing each pointer with a smart pointer will result in the same problem (using `unique_ptr<>`) or a memory leak (using `shared_ptr<>`). Use of `weak_ptr<>` for a parent pointer, is overkill: the tree invariants (`x->left->parent == x`, etc) guarantee that `parent` is always valid.

Comment: @JoergB: I didn't suggest to "blindly replace" them. I suggested using "smart pointers", which means `shared_ptr` for owning references, and `weak_ptr` (or regular pointers, if dangling references are not an issue) for non-owning references.

Answer (score 2):

Any ownership relationship (where an object is responsible for deleting another when that object is not needed any more) must not have cycles. In your case you have parent nodes owning their children and vice versa.

When the root node is deleted, it constructor will first delete the left child. The child's destructor will the delete the parent, which is already being deleted.

A typical ownership relationship in tree is that parent nodes own their children. The children have a pointer to the parent that does not carry ownership. That pointer will remain valid for the lifetime of the child node, because the child will be deleted as part of the destruction of the parent.

So your destructor should simply do:

```
BST_Node::~BST_Node() {
   delete left;
   delete right;
}
```

Additional notes:

- You don't need to check for NULL pointers - deleting a nullpointer is
  safe and will do nothing.
- You should prevent copying of BST_Node objects. The implicitly
  defined copy constructor and copy assignment operator will create
  another object that owns the same child nodes, also resulting in
  double deletion of objects.

The best way to express ownership semantics of pointers is using a suitable smart pointer class. In your case, the most appropriate declaration would be to have

```
class BST_Node {
    public:
        ~BST_Node() = default; // you can simply omit this completely

        // other things

        BST_Node* parent; // no ownership
        std::unique_ptr<BST_Node> left;  // exclusive ownership
        std::unique_ptr<BST_Node> right;
};
```

As a useful additional effect of this, the implicitly generated copy operations will be suppressed, because `std::unique_ptr<T>` is not copyable.

Comment: Another question, should I use std::shared_prt<BST_Node> for parent?

Comment: No. Any object should either have a single unique owner or may have multiple shared owners. You can't mix these types of ownership. With shared ownership you must still be careful that the "owns" relation has no cycles. Otherwise there is a memory leak: the objects will own each other and non of them can become the first to be destroyed (because it has no more owners). See my other comment elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Just running thru the code I see an issue in this segment

> ```
>     if (l_tmp)
>         l_tmp->parent = p;
>     p->left = l_tmp;
>     BST_Node* r_tmp = CreateTree(a, mid+1, end);
>     if (r_tmp)
>         r_tmp->parent = p;
>     p->right = r_tmp;
> ```

`l_tmp->parent` and `r_tmp->parent` both point to the same node `p`. Consequently there is a double delete of the node p, once when the destructor of l_tmp is called and again when the destructor of r_tmp is called. This might be the reason you are seeing the error.
As suggested by Andy in the comment, this seems to be a good scenario to use smart pointers.